# Order Model by the date difference of its has_many model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I don't know this is the exact and simple way I am implementing. I have a two model. Modal 'A' belongs to Modal 'B' and 'B' has many to Modal 'A'. I have a date field 'expiry date' in Model B.

Now I want to list out records the Modal 'A'. The list should be in ascending order with the difference of its associated Modal 'B' last record expiry date and today date. I calculated the date difference in view, but still confused to order it.

```
diff = (f.bill_histories.last.ndate.to_date - DateTime.now.to_date).to_i
```

I tried and google it, but still didn't find suggestion. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

assuming:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos
end
```

You should be able to sort on the database level using a join statement on the `Bar`s table:

```
Foo.joins(:bar).order(bars: { expired_at: :desc })
```

Explanation:

> ascending order with the difference of its associated Modal 'B' last record expiry date and today date

This means that the newest date should be first, so a simple `ORDER BY expired_at DESC` should do what you need.

The `join` is necessary so you can use the `Bar`s `expired_at` column.

The hash syntax in the `order` method is needed to access the join table's attribute.

Comment: This way I can list out the Modal A with Model B expiry date, however, my concern is bit different. I want to order the Modal A list with the days difference of expiry date and  current date

Comment: @SantoshAryal What's the difference? Sorting by the expire date in descending order is the same as sorting on the date difference in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the difference `Time.zone.now - model_b_object.expiry_date` is an unnecessary step. Just go directly to the ordering part. This will show the model B records that expired nearest to Today's date.

`ModelB.all.order("expiry_date ASC")`

Comment: I checked the difference because I need to show the total remaining days in Modal A list, and also I need to short the Modal A list based on the last expiry date of Modal B getting the expiry date from the last record of Modal B.